# C++ CURL: treating header and body data differently

Tags: c++, curl, overloading

I wish to write a C++ program to save the returned header to a variable and save the returned body to a text file. How can I do this?

Currently, my approach is to overload the `handleData` function, but the compiler returns the error `overloaded function with no contextual type information`. This is what I have written so far (an extract of the code):

```
static size_t handleData(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string *str){ 
    string temp = string(ptr);
    // catch the cookie 
    if (temp.substr(0,10)=="Set-Cookie"){
       *str = temp;
    }
    return size * nmemb;
}

static size_t handleData(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream){ 
    int written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

FILE *bodyfile;
string *return_header = new string;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, handleData); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, return_header);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, bodyfile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html) instead.

```
static size_t handleHeader(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, string *str){ 
    // ...
}
static size_t handleData(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream){ 
    // ...
}

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, handleHeader);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, handleData); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, return_header);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, bodyfile);
```